# How I get accurcy graph(not dot) like loss graph in Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I want continuous accuracy in tensorboard (not dot...) like loss graph.

I use: `dnnclassifier model`, `build_estimator`, `input_fn`, `trains` and `eval` (like in Tensorflow tutorial).

Please help me.

```
def build_estimator(model_dir):
    m = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        model_dir=model_dir,
        feature_columns=deep_columns,
        n_classes=10,
        hidden_units=[512, 256],
        config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=1)
    )

    return m

def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle):
    labels = data_file['RATING'].astype(int)

    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=data_file,
        y=labels,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        num_threads=5)

def trains_and_eval( train_data, test_data, train_steps ):
    model_dir = "./board/sample"

    m = build_estimator(model_dir)

    m.train( input_fn=input_fn( train_data, num_epochs=1, shuffle=True), steps=train_steps)

    results = m.evaluate( input_fn=input_fn(test_data, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False), steps=None)

    for key in sorted(results):
        print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

[image]

Comment: Please put more effort into English, formatting and punctuation. Minor language problems are understandable but low quality formatting and/or punctuation misuse and/or severe grammar issues show a lack of respect for people reading the post.

Answer (score 0):

Each data point in the "accuracy" plot is generated when you call `m.evaluate()`. Since you only call `m.evaluate()` once, the graph contains only one point.

Modifying your program to call `m.evaluate()` more than once will lead to a continuous plot. For example, you could add a loop around the calls to `m.train()` and `m.evaluate()`:

```
for _ in range(10):
  m.train(input_fn=input_fn(train_data, num_epochs=1, shuffle=True),
          steps=train_steps)

  results = m.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn(test_data, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False),
                       steps=None)
```

The recently added (in TensorFlow 1.4) [`tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) function might also help to automate this process.

Comment: however, average_loss is graph(multi_point).
Accuracy x point range is so narrow, Other plot x point range is 200.
How I chage accuracy x range?

Comment: The x range is determined by the global step at the times when you evaluate the model. Currently, the accuracy graph only includes a single point (at `x = 1000`). Adding more points will increase the range.